# Update Column - Based on 25% based on certain columns

Tags: sql, oracle

in oracle database, I have a table ITEM_MASTER, that has the columns

```
ITEM
DEPT
CLASS
SUBCLASS
RANGE
```

within  every combination of dept, class, subclass
I need 25% of the records to be updated with 1,2,3,4 respectively in the range column

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for NTILE analytical function here -

```
SELECT ITEM, DEPT, CLASS, SUBCLASS,
       NTILE(4) OVER(PARTITION BY DEPT, CLASS, SUBCLASS ORDER BY ITEM) RANGE
  FROM ITEM_MASTER;
```

Here 4 represents 25%. Read about it [in detail.](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/ntile-analytic-function)